# slider with fractions of numbers

Tags: javascript, dojo, slider

I have a slider from 1 to 0.1.
I set the minimum and maximum and slider calculates the interval between numbers.

But now i need to use a set of numbers between 1/1, 1/2, ... to 1/9. (e.g. 1, 0.5, 0.33, 0.25, ...)

How can i make that ?

```
<div id="slider1" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.HorizontalSlider"
        data-dojo-props='name:"horizontal1",
            onChange:function(val){ dojo.byId("slider1input").value=dojo.number.format(val); },

            maximum:1/9,
            minimum:1/1,
            showButtons:true,
            discreteValues:9,
            intermediateChanges:true,
            style:{width:"400px"}
            '>
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/avunuz/edit#preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified example from the [demo page](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/Slider):

```
<div id='slider1'
 data-dojo-type='dijit.form.HorizontalSlider'
 data-dojo-props='name:"horizontal1",
                  onChange: function(val){ dojo.byId("slider1input").value = dojo.number.format( 1 / (10 - val) ); },
                  maximum: 9,
                  minimum: 1,
                  showButtons: true,
                  discreteValues: 9,
                  intermediateChanges: true,
                  style: {width:"400px"}'>

<ol dojoType="dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels" container="topDecoration" style="height: 1.5em; font-size: 75%; color: gray;">
    <li>1/9</li>
    <li>1/8</li>
    <li>1/7</li>
    <li>1/6</li>
    <li>1/5</li>
    <li>1/4</li>
    <li>1/3</li>
    <li>1/2</li>
    <li>1</li>
</ol>
<div dojoType="dijit.form.HorizontalRule" container="bottomDecoration" count=9 style="height:5px;"></div>
```

So the slider accepts integer numbers and then transforms them into your fractions, see `onChange` function.